# count 0 digits places in factorial result without memory exception

Tags: php, cakephp, math, logic, mathematical-optimization

I want to find 0 digits after decimal results of factorial number ***without using as a string and in bulit functions*** .

```
 For e.g.
 Number                     Factoial result         count of 0 occured after nums
   1!                         = 1                                     => 0
   5!                         = 120                                   => 1
   10!                        = 3628800                               => 2
   15!                        = 1307674368000                         => 3
```

As per last column i want to find out the total count of "0" at last number.***Without having memory exception*** in php.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what problem are you having? Working out the factorial or counting the zeroes? And neither should result in memory exceptions unless you're doing something weird like recursion!

Comment: For which inputs are you running out of memory?

Comment: I have problem with counting number zeroes.It should run for any number

Comment: How are you trying to count the zeroes then? Show code!

Comment: So, do you care about the factorials in particular? There is a very short solution for those.

Comment: Any number? Do you really want this to run for factorials of 1 million+ digit numbers? That would be very surprising, but doable. If not, please actually answer which inputs currently cause you to run out of memory.

Comment: `$zeroCount = strlen($result) - strlen(rtrim($result,'0'));`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailing_zero

Comment: The problem that OP didn't really explain is that computing `n!`  results in memory exceptions once `n` is at all large.  The trick is to use the idea in Douglas Zare's link to count the number of zeros without having to find `n!`.  But this also feels like a homework problem where OP hasn't done any work at all.

Comment: @Teepeemm: There is actually something much better than what is currently on that Wikipedia page. Instead of summing floor(n/5^i) you can compute (n-digitSumBase5(n))/4, and you can compute the digit sum base 5 in a simple loop. I wonder whether this is one of the exercises on a site like Project Euler.

Answer (score 0):

I provide you a function using `substr`. You can try this

```
function countLastZero($num){
    $count = 0;
    while(strlen($num) > 0){
        $las = substr($num, -1);
        if($las == 0){
            $count++;
            $num = substr($num, 0, strlen($num) - 1);
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}

echo countLastZero(1307674368000); //output 3
```

Comment: @DouglasZare thank you. I noticed that & updated answer!